# DecimalFormat in reactive forms (with live calculation)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following edit-component, where amount * price results in worth

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Menge</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="new_unit_amount" type="number" (change)="calculateWorth()" matInput required />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Stückpreis (EUR)</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="new_unit_price" type="number" (change)="calculateWorth()" matInput />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Wert (EUR)</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="new_unit_worth" type="number" matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    new_unit_amount: new FormControl(this.currentUnit.unit_amount, [Validators.required]),
    new_unit_price: new FormControl(this.currentUnit.unit_price),
    new_unit_worth: new FormControl({ value: (this.currentUnit.unit_amount * this.currentUnit.unit_price), disabled: true })
});

calculateWorth(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.get('new_unit_price').value === null && this.formGroup.get('new_unit_amount').value === null) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: 0
        })
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('new_unit_price').value === null) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: 0
        })
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('new_unit_amount').value === null) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: 0
        })
    } else {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: +this.formGroup.get('new_unit_price').value * +this.formGroup.get('new_unit_amount').value
        })
    }
}
```

My problem is that initial and calculated values do not show up with 2 decimals. Therefore I imported DecimalPipe in my app.module.ts as a provider and tried this for example:

```
new_unit_price: new FormControl(this.decimalPipe.transform(this.currentUnit.unit_price, '1.0-2'))
```

I also had a try with CurrencyPipe and other examples from a web research:

```
new_unit_price: new FormControl(this.currencyPipe.transform(this.currentUnit.unit_price, 'de-DE', '1.0-2'))
```

But at least the input-field stay empty. So my question is, what would be the right approach to show up the values with 2 decimals.

Thx and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple javascript toFixed Function to solve this.

```
parseFloat(decimalValue).toFixed(2);

this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    new_unit_amount: new FormControl(parseFloat(this.currentUnit.unit_amount).toFixed(2), [Validators.required]),
    new_unit_price: new FormControl(parseFloat(this.currentUnit.unit_price).toFixed(2)),
    new_unit_worth: new FormControl({ value: parseFloat(this.currentUnit.unit_amount * this.currentUnit.unit_price).toFixed(2), disabled: true })
});

calculateWorth(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.get('new_unit_price').value === null && this.formGroup.get('new_unit_amount').value === null) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: 0
        });
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('new_unit_price').value === null) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: 0
        });
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('new_unit_amount').value === null) {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: 0
        });
    } else {
        const newWorth = (parseFloat(this.formGroup.get('new_unit_price').value) * parseFloat(this.formGroup.get('new_unit_amount').value)).toFixed(2)
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
        new_unit_worth: newWorth 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I just needed the "toFixed(2)" function, because the value are numbers/floats by default. Anyway thx

Comment: But remember, toFixed function return the value as a string. So, while using input value, always wrap it into parseFloat first.